# Does Protection enchantment work against damage done by the Thorns enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the 'Protection' enchantment protect you from some of the damage caused by hurting another player wearing armor with the enchantment 'Thorns'?

Answer (score 2):

I just experimented with it. Yes it does protects against Thorns. In fact, protection enchantment reduces all damage except for void damage and /kill command.
Video : [image: Watch video on youtube]

Comment: Great answer! - But it'd be helpful if you actually explained why. (A video is great, we can see it works - But why?)

Comment: @aytimothy I'm not sure what's exactly going on in-game but [according to wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Protection#Protection) protection enchantment reduces all damage except for void damage and /kill command.

Comment: Then add that into your answer :) (You know you can edit it right?) Click to edit: [edit] or the 'edit' button under the YouTube video. btw, that *exactly* is what's going on.